# Should processing have language hints for its code?

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

In the question:

[assigning location dots to image on processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124638/assigning-location-dots-to-image-on-processing?noredirect=1#comment31790557_21124638)

I mistaken thought via the tags that the question was about algorithms and processing *data* not the processing language. This was reinforced by the fact that the code was not auto highlighted. Could we associate the proper code formatting for `[processing]`?

Comment: Maybe the tag should be [tag:processing-lang]?

Comment: If you hover the mouse over the tag, the definition indicates that it refers to the processing language.

Comment: @KenWhite Absolutely true, and the tags were correct. I'm suggesting that the proper code hinting apply to it.

Comment: @Hooked: I'm aware (which is why I didn't post my comment as an answer). I was offering a suggestion to avoid the "mistaken thought" in the future. :-)